Conditional Github Actions step does not execute while condition is met
I have a Github Actions workflow running on my repository to deploy my application.In this actions I have 2 steps to check if an image of my application already exists and to back it up if it exists.
- name: Check if latest image exists
  id: check_latest_image
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ env.SSH_HOST }}
    username: ${{ env.SSH_USER }}
    password: ${{ env.SSH_PASSWORD }}
    key: ${{ env.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    port: ${{ env.SSH_PORT }}
    script: |
      if docker image inspect crm/api-publisher-consumer:latest &> /dev/null;
      then
        echo "::set-output name=image_exists::true"
      else  
        echo "::set-output name=image_exists::false"
      fi

- name: Backup previous state
  if: steps.check_latest_image.outputs.image_exists == 'true'
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ env.SSH_HOST }}
    username: ${{ env.SSH_USER }}
    password: ${{ env.SSH_PASSWORD }}
    key: ${{ env.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    port: ${{ env.SSH_PORT }}
    script: |
      cd ~/TestServer/crm/crm-api
      docker tag crm/api-publisher-consumer:latest crm/api-publisher-consumer:backup

To my knowledge it sets the output named image_exists to true in step "check_latest_image" and then checks the output in the if conditional in step "Backup previous state", if it exists.
The issue is that step "Backup previous state" is never run while the output of "check_latest_image" does appear to be set correctly.
partial logs to step "check_latest_image"
======CMD======
if docker image inspect crm/api-publisher-consumer:latest &> /dev/null;
then
  echo "::set-output name=image_exists::'true'"
else  
  echo "::set-output name=image_exists::'false'"
fi

======END======
out: ::set-output name=image_exists::'true'
==============================================
✅ Successfully executed commands to all host.
==============================================

I have tried swapping around the variables to strings and booleans because I thought something there may be going wrong, but no luck.

Here's the related open GitHub issue. Not merged yet. See this issue for the workaround.

Nice the workaround did the trick. Thx for the comment!
